# JavaScript Loop bug infinite loop

Tags: javascript, loops, debugging, crash, infinite

I am doing my first game snake, but I have a problem which appears sometime when I eat a rectangle and try to generate another my script crashes and I have an infinite loop.

```
var coincide = false;
         var cmpt;
         do {
             mangey = Math.random();
             mangey *= canvas.height;
             t = mangey % 20;
             mangey -= t;
             mangex = Math.random();
             mangex *= canvas.width;
             t = mangex % 20;
             mangex = mangex - t;
             for (cmpt = 0; cmpt < snake.length; cmpt++) {
                 if ((snake[cmpt][0] == mangex) && (snake[cmpt][1] == mangey)) {
                     coincide = true;
                     alert(snake);
                     console.log(mangex,mangey);
                 }
             }
         }
         while ((coincide) || ((mangex > 480) || (mangex < 0)) || ((mangey > 380) || (mangey < 0)));
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When `coincide = true;`, it never changes, so it is constantly true, hence the infinite loop. So I'd add an else statement:

```
if ((snake[cmpt][0] == mangex) && (snake[cmpt][1] == mangey))
{
  coincide = true;
  alert(snake);
  console.log(mangex,mangey);
}
else
{
  coincide = false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but still don't work , this code test if the generated position of the next rectangle to eat is the same for a postion which is occuped by the hole snake so if it is the same we have to generate an other position . so we have to conserve the change of "coincide" if it is the same .

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved , Thank you for views .
In the previous code : When we have coincide=true it will not change even when the generated rectangle do not have an intersection . 
Solution is simple it's just a we suppose that coincide =false before the for loop .
Great :D